# How do a make a cookie in Laravel and specify the SameSite attribute (Lax, None, Strict)?

Tags: laravel, cookies, laravel-8, samesite

I'm currently setting a cookie like this (in middleware):

```
cookie()->queue("loginToken", $loginToken, 60*24*365*10);
```

How do I specify SameSite = None?

I'm using Laravel 8.

Answer (score 10):

in config/session.php

```
'same_site' => "none",
```

Comment: I think the "none" needs quotation marks around it, because it should be a string.

Comment: This is close, but I think not exactly the right answer.  This only sets the SameSite setting for session cookies, not any custom cookie I want to set.

Comment: Didn't change anything for me for some reason. Still getting the same errors

Answer (score 2):

The `cookie` function declaration is:

```
function cookie($name = null, $value = null, $minutes = 0, $path = null, $domain = null, $secure = null, $httpOnly = true, $raw = false, $sameSite = null)
```

And `queue` just forwards the parameters, so you can do:

```
cookie()->queue("loginToken", $loginToken, 60*24*365*10, null, null, null, true, false, 'None');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did.  Remember, this is in the handle function of the middleware.

```
    $response = $next($request);

    // https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#setting-cookies
    // https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.3/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Cookie.php
    $cookie = \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie::create("loginToken")
        ->withValue($loginToken)
        ->withExpires(strtotime("+12 months"))
        ->withSecure(true)
        ->withHttpOnly(true)
        ->withSameSite("strict")
        ;

    $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also set it in the path of `config/session.php` but it's a bit hacky

```
'path' => '/; SameSite=None; secure'
```